# EU citizen ( working in UK) married to non EEA citizen: which application to file?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am an EU citizen living  and working in the UK.
I would like to have my husband (non EU citizen) join me.

Where can we find the appropriate family/spouse visa application, which he has to file from abroad?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll find the information you need via the Gov.uk site: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit

Comment: It should be noted that an EEA family permit is not necessary for those who are nationals of visa-exempt countries.